# Using database connection on multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

let's say I have a database connection in the class `Database` which offers the following public methods

```
public synchronized void open() {}
public synchronized void close() {}
public synchronized void addData(Object data) {}
```

My main program looks as follows:

```
Database databaseConnector = new Database();

for (Feed feed : feedList) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    FeedTimerTask timerTask = new FeedTimerTask(feed, databaseConnector, stopWords);
    // Run the task every five minutes.
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000 * 60 * 5);
}
```

It is easy to see, that an unknown number of threads is repeated every 5 minutes. These threads itself read data from a feed, and try to save it to a database afterwards.

Since they are all using the same `Database` connection, it seems not clever to me to `open()` and `close()` the connection for every feed. Especially since one reader can close the connection while another is still trying to write something to this feed.

Instead I thought that I want something like this timeline:

```
(open) (write1) (write2) ... (writeN) (close) ... (wait 5 mins) (open) ... (close)
```

The idea is, that every 5 minutes exactly **one** connection is opened and after all the threads have written their data, is closes again. So far, I have the following solution.

I added `private int openConnections;` to the Database and modified the code as follows:

```
public synchronized void open() {
    if(openConnections++ == 0) {
        // Connect to the database, because we were not connected before
    }
}

public synchronized void(close) {
    if(--openConnections == 0) {
        // Close to the connections because this was the last one
    }
}
```

Now, in every Thread, I do the following:

```
db.open();
db.addData(...);
db.close();
```

With this strategy, it is always checked, if there is still a need for an open connection and in that case, the connection is not closed. And I don't plan to have more threads than `MAX_INT`. My question is: Is this a good idea? Are there better ways to achieve the same behavior? It works completely fine but I am wondering if there is another solution which I should prefer.

Comment: Database connection pooling exists for a reason (and you have indeed come across one of those reasons). However writing your own non-thread-safe bicycle is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use database connection pooling. I don't recommend writing your own. [Here's an explanation on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4041114/1339987). You can use [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) or read up more on your own by searching for "connection pooling."

Comment: Thanks for the link. This raises the question when to close a database connection? Since I don't need the connection for 5 minutes I thought it would be a good idea to close it and open it 5 minutes later when all the threads fire. Should I instead leave it open the whole time?

Comment: @Freddy likely you just keep a fixed number open at all times. You can finagle with min=X and max=Y, set them to autoclose after X minutes idle, etc. but I would aim for something simple.

Comment: I agree, simple is better. In my case the behavior of the application is completely deterministic. It will always sleep for 5 mins, there is no user interaction whatsoever. Should I really keep the connections open? This seems a bit too complicated. For non-deterministic applications, I would agree like a server which has user requests which are non-predictable.

Comment: @Freddy keeping the connections open is not *complicated*. If it's not expensive then probably just keep them open. You can put a timeout if you want. It shouldn't matter most of the time.

Comment: According to (this)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968125/mongodb-connection-pooling] question, the mongoDB driver does connection pooling for me. So it should be safe for me to `close()` the connection after I finish my task. Would you agree with that? Let's assume I actually **want** to close the connections after every run and I don't know the order of the threads. Is this then a reasonable idea? Because when I now call close and the other thread is in the middle of adding data, it fails.